# Logging in or out of an application using a RFID Reader

Tags: authentication, facebook-login, rfid

I would like to know is it possible to log in our out of an application that has "username" and "password" fields by using a RFID Reader?
Facebook application for example.
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, short answer is : Yes.

Long answer: It depends on real purpose and implementation, also it depends which RFID reader you are using.    If it acts as HID device, then it simulates keyboard input. In that case, you will need two different cards in a row, one for username and the other for password. 
Another way: you can use some RFID reader and make application which reads card content and parse it as keyboard input.  In that case, you can put username and password in card content and separate them with TAB character.  I've seen some good Mifare implementation with D-logic uFR reader (You can google the keywords for more info).

Comment: Could you please send me more information about the device to my email address?
slaky86@hotmail.com
Thank you.